# Rename URL Parameters in Struts 2

Tags: java, rest, struts2

I'm trying to write a RESTful Api function using the struts 2 framework, and I'd like to follow the naming convention of using hyphens, e.g.

```
.../param-name=...
```

instead of

```
.../paramname=...
```

or

```
.../param_name=...
```

However, java doesn't allow variables with hypens in the name. Is there any way, like a annotation or something that would let me change the parameter name (like this)?

```
@Param(name="param-name")
public String getParamName(){
...
}
```

Comment: The quickest might be to modify the existing params interceptor to replace `-[a-z]` sequences by removing the `-` and capitalizing all but the first; I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way or not. (Arguably that *is* the cleanest way, but there might be an *easier* way.)